# checkboxlisttile in flutter is not showing tick mark when checked

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have used checkboxlisttile in listview builder. Problem is even if I click on it there is no tick mark. But when I print the value it says true. When i click it again it is still true(not false) but with no tick mark.
Actually i am creating the list dynamically. I have a screen new_note.dart where I save a note in the database in note table. the saved node is displayed in this list in note_info.dart under all tabs. in completed tab I want to show completed notes i.e one which will be marked checked. I call this method getNotecheckList in TabBarView's container.

```
ListView getNotecheckList() {
    bool _isChecked=false;
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: count,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {

      return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text(this.noteList[position].note),
            subtitle: Text(this.noteList[position].actn_on),
            //secondary: const Icon(Icons.web),
            value:_isChecked,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                _isChecked=value;
              });
              },
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
          ),
      );

},);}
```

Everything in my code seems right. Then what is the mistake.
I even tried
_isChecked = ! _isChecked

note_info.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:vers2cts/models/note_model.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/models/customer_model.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/services/db_service.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/utils/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

import 'new_note.dart';


class Note_Info extends StatefulWidget{
  final String appBarTitle;
  final CustomerModel customer;

 
  Note_Info(this. customer, this.appBarTitle);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    
   return Note_InfoState(this. customer,this.appBarTitle);
  }

}

class Note_InfoState extends State<Note_Info> {
  DBService dbService = DBService();
  List<NoteModel> noteList;
  int count = 0;

  static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  NoteModel note=NoteModel();
  String appBarTitle;
  CustomerModel customer=new CustomerModel();
  Note_InfoState(this.customer, this.appBarTitle);


  bool rememberMe = false;
  DateTime _date = DateTime.now();
  TextEditingController custfNameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  updateListView();
    if (noteList == null) {
      noteList = List<NoteModel>();
      updateListView();
    }

    TextStyle titleStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead;
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var name=customer.first_name+" "+customer.last_name;
    custfNameController.text = name;

    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.add,

                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => NewNote(customer,note)));
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            body: Container(
              child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextField(controller: custfNameController,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),

                        textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      child: Row(children: [
                        ImageProfile(customer.cust_photo),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.call,
                              color: Colors.green,
                              size: 45,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {

                            },
                          ),
                        ),

                      ],),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                      child: AppBar(
                        bottom: TabBar(
                          tabs: [
                            Tab(
                              text: "All",
                            
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              text: "Pending",
                            
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              text: "Cancelled",
                             
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              text: "Completed",
                             
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    // create widgets for each tab bar here
                    Expanded(
                      child: TabBarView(
                        children: [
                          // first tab bar view widget
                          Container(
                              child: getNotecheckList()
                          ),

                          // second tab bar viiew widget
                          Container(

                          ),


                          Container(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'Cancelled',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(

                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'Completed',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 55.0,
                        width: 200,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          elevation: 2,

                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                          color: Theme
                              .of(context)
                              .primaryColorDark,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          child: Text('Save', textScaleFactor: 1.5,),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              //_reset();
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]
              ),
            )
        ));
  }

  Widget ImageProfile(String fileName) {
    return Center(
      child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 80.0,
          backgroundImage:  fileName == null
              ?AssetImage('images/person_icon.jpg')
              :FileImage(File(customer.cust_photo))),

    );

  }


  
  Future<void> updateListView() {
    final Future<Database> dbFuture = DB.init();
    dbFuture.then((database) {
      int cid=customer.cust_id;

      Future<List<NoteModel>> noteListFuture = dbService.getCustomerNotes(cid);
      noteListFuture.then((noteList) {

        setState(() {
          this.noteList = noteList;
          this.count = noteList.length;
        });
      });
    });
  }
  ListView getNotecheckList() {

    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: count,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {

          int _isChecked = -1;

        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text(this.noteList[position].note),
            subtitle: Text(this.noteList[position].actn_on),
            //secondary: const Icon(Icons.web),
            value: _isChecked,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                _isChecked = value;
              });
            },
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
            
              });
            },
                ),
            );
          },
         );
        }

  }
```

(There is no tag CheckboxListTile in stackoverflow)

Comment: why? that causes error. I have tried that

Comment: Where should I declare it then?? Because value is a required field.

Comment: It doesnt access from there

Comment: Can u plzz elaborate what should I do now actually

Answer (score 1):

Once you call `setState` it rebuild the `getNotecheckList()` but inside `getNotecheckList()` you set `bool _isChecked=false;` thst's why it's not working.

define it `Widget build(BuildContext context)`

```
....
bool _isChecked=false;
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ......
  }
```

Comment: I didnt get u. do u mean i should that variable at the top. I tried that but it doesnt access it. Actually i am calling this method in child: TabBarView(
                        `children: [
                          // first tab bar view widget
                          Container(
                              child: getNotecheckList()
                          ), `

Answer (score 0):

The State of widget is not preserved, that is why the checkmark is not showing.

this is a sample code. I have changed the bool to int, so we can track the position of selected item.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int _isChecked = -1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text("hi"),
            subtitle: Text("this.noteList[position].actn_on"),
            //secondary: const Icon(Icons.web),
            value: position== _isChecked,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                _isChecked = value?position:-1;
              });
            },
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried ur code but it doesnt seem to work. I am going to add my whole source code so that u get the idea

Comment: make sure that the `_isChecked` variable is declared outside the function body, like `count ` variable in your code.

Comment: ok thanks now its working but theres a problem when I check one all are checked

Comment: hope you have changed `bool` to `int` and ` value: position== _isChecked,`

Comment: OMG now its acting like radio button.. only one checkbox can be selected. But I want to to check multiple checkboxlisttiles

Comment: Can u please tell me how can I select multiple checkboxes here or do I need to post another question for that?

Comment: can you add `NoteModel` class